# I get two warnings after Ubuntu 22.04 update

Tags: apt, updates

I got this once update on Ubuntu 22.04, mentionable that I upgraded from 20.04

```
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because you have that old repository from the old Ubuntu
18.04 (Bionic Beever), as it specifies in the Warnings: `bionic-updates/` and `bionic-security`.

So to fix this, open your terminal and remove that/those repositories left behind from the old distro version.

You can use [this link](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/remove-an-apt-repository-ubuntu) and refer to [this useful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219344/439306) to learn how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked for me..

Comment: You're very welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution if it helped solve your issue.